# Trouble getting substring from Xpath

Tags: exception, xpath

Utilizing a browser console the following command returns a source path for an image file.

```
$x('//*[@class="full scale-horiz"]/@src')
```

Returns

https://images.thewebsite.com/img/p400/17732/12digitcodes.jpg

I am trying only to retrieve the 12digitcodes from the image path. No .jpg or anything else. I've tried using substring-before and substring-length but all I get are errors. They are either not a legal expression or it throws an exception.

I thought this command would do it:

```
$x('substring-before(//*[@class="full scale-horiz"]/@src, ".jpg")')
```

But it returns this error: TypeError: The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type.

Can someone help me out with this so I can get what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working, my original code returned an error on the Firefox console but works fine in the Chrome console. This is what I ended up using to get the 12 digit code I was trying to scrape. If there is a simpler/shorter command to do this please let me know. Thanks.

```
substring(substring-before(//*[@class="full scale-horiz"]/@src, ".jpg"), string-length(substring-before(//*[@class="full scale-horiz"]/@src, ".jpg"))-11)
```